# Quadrilaterals with adjacent sides equal

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Given a quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $AB=AD=10$ and $BC=CD=5$, which of the following can be a value of the angle $\angle BAD$?

(A) 45

(B)60

(C) 75

(D) 90

(E)122.5

Comment: Quadrilaterals are not rigid shapes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio-What do you infer from that?

Comment: @tatan: there are many kites for which $AB=AD=10$ and $BC=CD=5$. The angle $\widehat{BAD}$ is not fixed by such constraints.

Comment: @bia: You need to know one of angles along with four given sides to draw a unique quadrilateral

Comment: You need to know more. If you try to build that kind of quadrilateral from something you have (legos, strings or whatever) see that you can reshape it without alter the lengths.

Comment: We can find the angle if the opposite angle is given.

Comment: If the opposite angle is given we can use sine rule to find the other angle.

Comment: There is no other information given. And i would request everyone to please not downvote the question because you cant think of the answer. The info i have provided is the only info given in the question! Please suggest a solution on the basis of this given info if u can!

Answer (score 3):

An illustration why we don't have a fixed value for $\angle BAD$ [image]

Comment: Thanks for the illustration Quang! I just added a few answer choices i had misse adding earlier. Can you help me with the answer now?

Comment: Pls look at the picture. Angle $\angle BAD$ gets larger as $C$ gets closer to $A$. How close can $C$ get to $A$? What is that corresponding angle?

Comment: Umm the question only has as much given information as i have provided in mine...and the answer is 45. So, i'm sure there must be some geometric reasoning to eliminate the other options.

Comment: In that case, try to draw a picture with some other angle and see what goes wrong.